# Sum without highest and lowest number

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, math, arrow-functions

I've been spending a few hours trying to understand where the error is in this code. Debugging indicated that the output is 0 as it should be for any number less than 0. However, this code is still unable to pass the test:

```
function sumArray(array) 
{
  return array < 1 || array == null ? 0
    :array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array);
  
  }

console.log(sumArray([-3]))
```

Comment: Can we see the text of the problem?

Comment: First problem: you are checking whether `array < 1`.  Presumably you want to be checking if `array .length < 1`.  If you fix that, can you see what the next problem is?

Comment: Hint: it should work for arrays of length greater than 1.  What happens with single-element arrays?

Comment: Just because there's a ternary operator you don't have to use it. A good ol' `if` would be so much more readable: `if (array.length < 1 || array == null) { return 0; } ...` (also the order of the conditions doesn't make much sense...)

Comment: What should be the result for `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely better:

```
function sumArray(array) {
  
  if (array == null || array.length <= 1) {
    return 0
  }
  
  var max = Math.max(...array);
  var min = Math.min(...array);
  var sum = 0
  
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
   }

  return sum - max - min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumValues (array) {
if (array != null && array.length > 0) {    
  let min = Math.min(...array);  // lowest in array by spreading
  let max = Math.max(...array);  // highest in array by spreading

  // Sum up the numbers in the array
  let sum = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

  // Do the math
  let result = sum - max - min;
  if (result > 0) {
      return result
  } else {
      return 0
  }
 
} else {
    return 0
}
}

console.log(sumValues([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Comment: @Andreas rectified!

Comment: Only maybe you can add the condition  to the end```` result < 0 ? 0 : result ````
question says output should be 0 for any number less than 0.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ And empty arrays and `null`

Comment: I dunno. This solution doesn't handle various cases: duplicate values of max or min, negative values, array length = 1. The problem isn't well-specified as it stands -- the first problem OP needs to solve is to clarify what it means to "sum without highest and lowest number." It would be more helpful to OP to try to help him/her sort out the definition of the problem.

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you so much for the pointers. I've just started getting into javascript a few weeks ago but I felt like the solution could be done in a few lines of code. The problem was that it would work except for values less than 0.

Comment: This is what the task was asking: Sum all the numbers of a given array ( cq. list ), except the highest and the lowest element ( by value, not by index! ).

The highest or lowest element respectively is a single element at each edge, even if there are more than one with the same value.

Mind the input validation.